# Distinct query using MongoDB Driver for C# is much slower than the same query sent via MongoDB shell

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongo-shell

I have a Collection contains 1.5M records. When I query the collection using the mongo shell it return data in 2.0s and when I do the same using Mongo driver C# it takes 13-16s to return the list. I have implemented the indexes too on the collection.

**MongoShell Query** :

```
db.DiscountTMV.distinct("OriginId" ,{ $and : [
    {"LTLRates.CustomerId" : ObjectId("5faac93be2867c2748bcd6a7")},
    {"LTLRates.TenId" : ObjectId("5faac63be2867c2748ae95a8")},
    {"OriginId" : {$in :[  ObjectId("5faac922e2867c2748bcb745"),ObjectId("5faac922e2867c2748bcb73d"),ObjectId("5faac922e2867c2748bcb73f"),ObjectId("5faac922e2867c2748bcb741"),ObjectId("5faac922e2867c2748bcb71c"),ObjectId("5faac922e2867c2748bcb749"),
    ]}}
]})
```

The In operator for **OriginId** contains sometimes more than 200 Ids which are based on the conditions that user inputs.

**C# Code**:

```
var ratingFilter = Builders<DiscountTMV>.Filter.ElemMatch(x => x.LTLRates, x => x.TenId == tenId);

ratingFilter &= Builders<DiscountTMV>.Filter.ElemMatch(x => x.LTLRates, x => x.CustomerId == customerId);

ratingFilter &= Builders<DiscountTMV>.Filter.In("OriginId", filteredRegionIds);

var discountTiers = await _mContext.DiscountTMV.Distinct<string>("OriginId", ratingFilter).ToListAsync();
```

Another query that I tried is :

```
var ratingFilter = Builders<DiscountTMV>.Filter.Eq("LTLRates.TenId" == tenId);

ratingFilter &= Builders<DiscountTMV>.Filter.Eq("LTLRates.CustomerId" == customerId);

ratingFilter &= Builders<DiscountTMV>.Filter.In("OriginId", filteredRegionIds);

var discountTiers = await _mContext.DiscountTMV.Distinct<string>("OriginId", ratingFilter).ToListAsync();
```

Any one have any idea how can I achieve the same output performance using the C# Mongo driver or any suggestions. Also would be great if someone share the proper syntax of the same query to run in RunCommandAsync Method of MongoDb C# driver. Thanks in advance.

Below is the image of the stats of MongoDB query.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0w36m.png)

Comment: Obtain the query you are sending via C#, compare to the one used with shell.

Comment: Both queries are same.

Comment: Use a performance profiler if you suspect C# is slower than it should be, in this case.  Get some actual metrics.  If the difference is that large you'll quickly see where that time's spent.

Comment: Don't add links unless they are to quoted documentation. Place the images inline.

Answer (score 0):

The differences in query execution time, when querying from different environments, are due to:

- Different queries being executed. Use [command monitoring](https://docs.mongodb.com/ruby-driver/master/tutorials/ruby-driver-monitoring/#command-monitoring) to obtain the actual queries sent by the driver.
- The query not actually being executed by one of the environments. Some of the query methods are lazy and don't actually issue the queries until results are iterated.
- Different number of results requested (first batch vs all of them).
- Different data types requiring different amounts of time to serialize/deserialize to/from BSON in the two environments.

To troubleshoot, verify that:

- In both sitations the query is actually executed.
- The same exact query is being sent.
- The same number of documents are retrieved from the result set (e.g. all of them).
- The data types, in both the query and the results, are as simple as possible (try integers or short strings).

If you've done all of the above and are still seeing different execution times, update the question with the gathered information demonstrating everything above is matching up.